# Замыливание элементов при трансформации в хроме

Tags: html, css, webkit, transform

Имеются элементы к которым применена анимация + 3д-трансформация + трансформация масштаба.
В файрфоксе все норм, а в хроме по завершению анимации элементы со всеми дочерними блюрятся.
Каким образом можно это исправить?

В ФФ так:

[image: В Файрфоксе]

В Хроме так:

[image: В Хроме]

Comment: `transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` к элементам, что размываются

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это, увы, не помогает.
Так же will-change с этим не справляется.
Посмотреть как это выглядит, можно здесь:
https://vk.com/app5494316_317106694

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена(шрифт стал читабельным) путем изменения сотых доль масштаба(transform:scale(0.72))